# Searching for "import" shows results for "important"

Tags: support, search

I searched for [`[git] import`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[git]+import), but the top results only contain the word "important", rather than the expected results about importing data into a Git repository:

[image: example]

It looks like Stack Exchange's search is overzealously [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) the search query, since "importance" is a legitimate (but literary, and very unlikely in a search query) sense of the word *import*.

I know I can work around it by using double quotes to disable stemming completely; the spurious stemming is a bug.

Comment: There's no bug here.  @ShaWizDowArd's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes are your friend!

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22import%22

> [image]

To search for whole words, just wrap with quotes same way like when using Google.

Comment: I know I can work around it; the bug is the spurious stemming.

Comment: OK, I see now. Fair enough, though it's quite minor issue in my opinion.

Comment: There's no bug here.

Comment: @Ben I agree, you'll have to convince the OP.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd nope, there's no `bug` tag anymore ;-)  Just like that!