# Do not do stemming for some search terms (HTTPS, ...)

Tags: feature-request, search

Using the SO search engine to look for [questions and answers about `HTTPS`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HTTPS) gives plenty of results about HTTP, but articles about HTTP are not at the top of the list of relevant articles. [Searching about `"HTTPS"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22HTTPS%22) (in quotes) gives what is expected.

More realistically, the search engine does not work well when looking for questions about redirecting HTTP to HTTPS. [Querying without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=redirect%20HTTP%20to%20HTTPS%20is:question) gives useless results. [Querying with quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=redirect%20HTTP%20to%20%22HTTPS%22%20is:question) gives useful results. This also means that the *Related* questions links for questions about HTTPS are not as relevant as they ought to be.

I guess this is because the SO search engine does "stemming" of search terms: converting plural nouns to singular nouns, and such like. That is almost always the right thing to do for a search engine. But for searching about `HTTPS` on SO (and perhaps other technical terms and on other SE sites, too) the *precise* word is important, and stemming is the wrong thing to do.

Expecting users to know they must search for "HTTPS" rather than HTTP seems unreasonable to me.

Could the search engine be configured so stemming was not done on words such as HTTP? If that functionality is already present, please could HTTPS/http be added to the list of words not porcessed by the stemming algorithm.

Comment: Workaround - search based on tag instead of text.  You just need to put brackets around the tag name, so you could search for `[https]` and get a host of questions tagged with [tag:https].

Comment: Most users are not going to know to search by tag. And not all questions are so specifically tagged.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183784/searching-for-import-shows-results-for-important

Comment: Better workaround: [use quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22HTTPS%22). (Still, I agree that this would be a useful exception to add. Nobody's going to search for "five HTTPs".)

Comment: HTTPS is very generic term. Doing a contextual search for HTTPS is likely to give a lot of false positives to questions or answers that have nothing to do about it. Your best bet is to search by tag, `[https]`.

Comment: @Raedwald short terms that match tags (like c#) are automatically converted to a tag search.  A better feature request might be to increase the length of words to convert to a tag search.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen True, but irrelevant. My question was prompted by a question about redirecting HTTPS to HTTP. Querying [without quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=redirect+HTTP+to+HTTPS+is%3Aquestion) gives useless results. Querying [with quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=redirect+HTTP+to+%22HTTPS%22+is%3Aquestion) gives useful results. This also means that the "relevant questions" links for questions about HTTPS are not as relevant as they ought to be.

Comment: @Raedwald ok, from that example, converting to a tag search is obviously not going to fix this problem (nor is a straight tag search).  It might be worthwhile to include that specific example in your question, as that clearly demonstrates a need.